# C# ClickOnce Application Elevated Privileges

Tags: c#, clickonce

I have a ClickOnce Application that elevates user privileges when the program is started, but installs all the ClickOnce files at the local user's AppData folder. The problem I'm running into is the elevated user doesn't have these config files in its own AppData folder. Basically, I need user A (without read/write permissions) to install the application. Once the application has been installed and opened, elevate privileges with account user B for reading/writing, which restricts user A from being able to view the data normally.

Is this even achievable with ClickOnce?

Comment: Maybe first try some simple solutions, like copying that configuration file to the shared location before evelating to user B.

Comment: @Evk I was thinking that would work and I haven't tried it yet. Going to do that now. Thanks.